# AKS API Load testing error: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body

Tags: api, flask, kubernetes, tornado, azure-aks

While load testing, after some successful responses from the API, JMeter records errors:
'Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body'.

From logs inside the code the response seems to complete normally.

The APP is deployed on AKS with ingress nginx/1.15.10 controllers. The APP consists of 4 separate APIs (one master calling the 3 others). The APIs are created in FLASK with CONNEXION and run in a WSGIContainer on a Tornado HTTPServer.

Another confusing factor is that the APP is deployed on two AKS instances on the same cluster. The one deployment does not return errors and the other does.

What could be causing the error?

Comment: can you provide more info, one master, three slaves, is that al 4 containers running inside a single pods ? When you say you have 2 pods running on two different nodes, are those the master pod of the slave pods ? when testing your app, you are using the nginx endpoint ? have you tried hitting the app svc instead or even the app directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to limit your testing scope.

1) target the application directly (bypassing the k8s svc and ingress controller). ensure you target each app running on the two different nodes. Do you still see the issue ?

2) target the app service directly (bypassing ingress controller), ensure you target each app running on the two different nodes. Do you still see the issue ?

3) target the app using its ingress, ensure you target each app running on the two different nodes. Do you still see the issue ?

Based on those results, we should be able to pinpoint better the source of your issue.